# Allocating global variables on multiple GPUs

Tags: cuda

I have a code working on a single GPU. In that code, I used

```
__device__ uint32_t aaa;
```

This line at the begining of code declared a global variable on the only involved device.

Now I want to use multiple devices (two or more), but I don't know how to allocate global variables in this case.

I think I should use `cudaSetDevice()` but I wonder where I should call this function.

Comment: Do you want a single instance of `aaa` or an instance of `aaa` for each GPU?

Comment: I mean the latter part.

Comment: Each global `__device__` variable is replicated per GPU.

Comment: You mean just writting __device__ uint32_t aaa this line will allocate a variable on each GPU ?

Comment: Thanks Robert. I figure out that.

Comment: In host code, you will be accessing whichever one corresponds to your most recent `cudaSetDevice()` call.  In device code, you will be accessing whichever one corresponds to the device that your device code is executing on.

Comment: But I have one more question. Why allocation manners are different between __device__ variable and combination of cudaSetDevice and cudaMalloc ? How can I allocate variable on each device by just typing __device__ although I did't specify each device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a variable like this:

```
__device__ int myval;
```

It is created at global scope.  An allocation for it is made in the GPU memory of each device that is present when your application is launched.

In host code (when using such functions as `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()`), you will be accessing whichever one corresponds to your most recent `cudaSetDevice()` call. In device code, you will be accessing whichever one corresponds to the device that your device code is executing on

The `__device__` declaration is at global scope (and statically allocated) in your program.  Variables at global scope are set up without the help of any runtime activity.  Therefore there is no opportunity to specify which devices the variable should be instantiated on, so CUDA instantiates those variables on all devices present.  Dynamically allocated device variables however are allocated using the runtime calls `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` and so we can precede these calls with a `cudaSetDevice` call in a multi-GPU system, and so the CUDA runtime manages these variables on a per-device basis, which is consistent with the behavior of most CUDA runtime API calls, which operate on the most recently selected device via `cudaSetDevice`.